# MVC using Linq to Entity w/ sql encryption

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, encryption, linq-to-entities

Currently i am using sql encryption and would like to continue using it through Linq.  I have all my CRUD stored proc's wired up to the table in order to handle the encryption/decryption on the backend.  Problem is my database model see's a field type of varbinary(max) which is used for the sql encryption storage.  The retrieval sp for this table does the decryption thus returning a string value.  How does one get around this.  Seems like the model needs to recognize a string in place of the varbinary but i am unsure of how to handle this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So change the table mapping to a view mapping in the database model?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, some choices:

1. Edit the ssdl manually.
2. Make a view and map that (you don't need to actually use it for anything but mapping).